# Bootstrap-weekpicker plugin post date format in form

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am new to coding so sorry for my probebly easy question.

I am using the plugin Week-Picker-Bootstrap-4. I allows me to open a callender and choose a week. The bootstrap-weekpicker.min.js creates a html input form with the following output after selecting the date `Week 41, 2021`.  This is ok for me but I need this value to be send to my server using post. But now it will post the `Week 41, 2021`. Is there a way to keep the value `Week 41, 2021` present for the user to see but to post the original selected date in this format `format :'yyyy-mm-dd'` as value to my server? I can not find a answer on how to do this.

```
              <div class="row">            
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">Week / Year</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
<div class="col-auto">
<div class="input-group date align-items-center">
                   
          <div class="input-group date align-items-center">
                 <div id="planning_weekpick"></div>
   </div></div>
    </div></div>
   
      </div>
//Bootstrap css and jquery are inlcuded to.
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/pingcheng/bootstrap4-datetimepicker/master/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/pingcheng/bootstrap4-datetimepicker/master/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
      <script src="../js/bootstrap-weekpicker.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
          <script type="text/javascript">
          $(function () {

  $('#planning_weekpick').weekpicker();

});

       
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can it with [this](https://lornajane.net/posts/2011/getting-dates-from-week-numbers-in-php) solution. It is [setISODate](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/datetime.setisodate.php) function.

```php
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setISODate($year, $weekNumber);
echo $date->format('Y.m.d');
```

There are several methods to extract year and week numbers from `Week 41, 2021` string.

For example:

```php
$dateString = 'Week 41, 2021';
$parts = explode(' ', $dateString);
$weekNumber = (int) rtrim($parts[1], ',');
$year = (int) $parts[2];
```

UPD:

May I suggest another way to write your normalizeMonth function:

```php
function normalizeMonth(int $monthNumber) {
  $months = ['Januari', 'Februari', 'Maart', 'April', 'Mei', 'Juni', 'Juli', 'Augustus', 'September', 'Oktober', 'November', 'December'];

  return $months[$monthNumber - 1]; // -1 because array indexes start with 0.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. Problem is that this format does not have the month in it. That is why i am searching for a way to make the post value as original date. From there i can use php to extract month, week, day and year.

Comment: So a way to get month, year, day, week values from “week 41, 2021” in php is also a answer for me. But i only see ways to get week and year from that and i know how to get all from the original date yyyy-mm-dd in php.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the code and document suggestion of @shanginn. I was able to create the folwoing code to got what i needed ! Many thanks !

```
$dateString = $planning_week;
$parts = explode(' ', $dateString);
$weekNumber = (int) rtrim($parts[1], ',');
$year = (int) $parts[2];
$weekyear = $weekNumber. '-' . $year;

$date = new DateTime();
$date->setISODate($year, $weekNumber);
$createddate = $date->format('Y-m-d');
$dateplanning = new DateTime($createddate);
$monthnumber = $dateplanning->format("m");
$yearandmonth = $year . '-' . $monthnumber;

function normalizeMonth($monthnumber) {
    switch($monthnumber) {
        case "01": return "Januari";
        case "02": return "Februari";
        case "03": return "Maart";
        case "04": return "April";
        case "05": return "Mei";
        case "06": return "Juni";
        case "07": return "Juli";
        case "08": return "Augustus";
        case "09": return "September";
        case "10": return "Oktober";
        case "11": return "November";
        case "12": return "December";
        
    }
    
    return $monthnumber;
}
$month = normalizeMonth($monthnumber);
```

Comment: It is a good practice to name your variables in [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) or in [snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) for better readability. Also there is another way to write function normalizeMonth(), please check my answer, I will update it with the function.

Comment: Thank you for the tip !. The month function you made, is it returning only the month in question or does is return all the months? I need only the current posted month turned into the tekst version.

Comment: it'll return only current month. please check the [array documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) for better understanding the function :)

Comment: Allright, nice ! Can you explain why its better to write the function your way?

Comment: I didn't say it is better. But in general, if you can avoid `if`s or `switch`es, you should do so. It is easier to understand and works faster. And just shorter. But my function relying on the fact that `$monthNumber` is between 1 and 12 which is true if you using `->format('m')`, but not always.